# Binomial coefficients from a combinatorial point of view

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I am just trying to understand binomial coefficients (nCr) from a combinatorial point of view, instead of the Pascal triangle.

Consider (x + y)^n, where the coefficient of the term x^(n-r)y^r is nCr.

My intuition is that say we throw 2 coins each time, and do this for n times (the intuition being that the first coin represents the variable x and the second coin represents the variable y).

And note the number of times where the first/second coin shows Head/Tail, with the condition being that after throwing this pair of coins for n times, the total number of Head/Tail is always equal to n (the intuition being that the power of x^(n-r) and the power of y^r always add up to (n-r) + r = n).

I haven't managed to show this mathematically. Hope my intuition is correct and that someone can help. :)

Comment: You seem to have two separate choices each time: (1) whether to use coin $x$ or coin $y$, and (2) whether the coin lands Heads or Tails.  But for $nCr$ you only need one of these.  Either just choose $x$ or $y$ each time, and $nCr$ is the number of ways you can do this choosing $x$ $r$ times, or flip a coin each time, and $nCr$ is the number of ways you can end up with $r$ Heads.  Don't do both.

Comment: If you flip both coins, instead of flipping only one coin, your analogy will break down.  That is, your analogy does not cover the situation where both coins are heads or both coins are tails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see why the coefficient of $x^{n-r}y^r$ in $(x+y)^n$ is $n \choose r$, imagine writing each copy of $(x+y)$ in the expansion
$$(x+y)^n=(x+y)(x+y)\cdots(x+y)$$
in a different color ink.
Then the coefficient of $x^{n-r}y^r$ is simply the number of ways one can pick $n-r$ colors out of $n$ colors. Each such choice corresponds with one subset of size $n-r$ of the $n$-set of copies of $(x+y)$, that subset being the copies contributing the $n-r$ factors of $x$ that go into $x^{n-r}y^r$. Of course, picking any $n-r$ colors to contribute the $x$’s leaves the remaining $r$ colors as the ones contributing the $y$’s.

With coin tosses, you could ask, “How many sequences of $n$ tosses of a single coin include exactly $n-r$ heads (and therefore also exactly $r$ tails)?” The answer amounts to the number of ways in which one can pick $n-r$ places out of $n$ to fill with the symbol *H*, with the remaining $r$ places filled with *T*’s.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am sure you are right I just need to let it sink in. :)